# Control.Parent = null

Tags: .net, winforms, custom-controls

I have my own control derived from Windows.Forms.Control and I am checking the Parent.BackColor inside the overrided of OnHandleCreated() method. At desing-time the Parent property first returns null, then - after form is completely loaded - returns the real parent window: the form itself.

We need to draw part of the custom control with the same color of the parent form background: when can we rely on the Control.Parent value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ParentChanged` event to detect when that property changes and trigger a redraw (though one *should* occur automatically). There are some properties, however (`BackColor` and `ForeColor` being two of them, I believe) that are "inherited" from the parent if not set explicitly, so you should be able to use those as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `if( this.DesignMode ) return;` to determine if your control is in design and not get exception or to do additional checking. In Windows Forms, after InitilizeComponents, afaik Control always have parent.

Comment: After `InitializeComponent` in the parent, that's correct. *Not* after `InitializeComponent` in the control.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I do not see problem here. Because as I understand you need parent for drawing something with parent back color, and when you receive your control's Paint event (OnPaint, WM_PAINT) parent already initialized.